# How to plot multiple polygons using CGAL::draw

Tags: cgal

How to plot multiple polygons using CGAL::draw() ? I wish to draw multiple polygons on the same frame. Cannot repeat the command as it is blocking in nature.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of overloaded functions `CGAL::draw` is very simple and very limited - there are fourteen of them and none of them can plot multiple polygons in the same frame.

You can plot anything you want using Qt - there are many examples how to do that in the CGAL `demo` directory. However it's much more involved than the `CGAL::draw` functions - you'll need to understand how to develop interactive Qt-based applications.

Answer (score 0):

CGAL seems to have added support for this since this question was asked.

Just use `#include <CGAL/Polygon_set_2.h>` and `#include <CGAL/draw_polygon_set_2.h>`, add your `Polygon_2` or `Polygon_with_holes_2` objects to a `Polygon_set_2` via the `Polygon_set_2::insert` method and then call `CGAL::draw` on the resulting polygon set.

A full example can be seen in [CGAL's documentation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Boolean_set_operations_2/Boolean_set_operations_2_2draw_polygon_set_8cpp-example.html).

Note that your polygons must be disconnected for the drawing to work as expected in this case.